# How can i send fax using perl script?

Tags: perl, fax

I want to send FAX using perl script.
How can I do it?
Is their any way send fax using perl script if any idea please tell me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have done ? Code Please

Comment: You can use [Win32::OLE](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE) to [send a fax using Perl on Windows](http://www.nu42.com/2015/04/send-fax-using-perl-on-windows.html).

Answer (score 1):

This older (6 yrs) thread on Perlmonks still seems like a good response to this question, in my opinion.

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=782340

Basically, if you have a fax server that has some more or less straightforward method of communicating with it programmatically (like HylaFax) then you can use Perl to interact with it in a familiar way.

If that is not the case then your best answer is to seek out an external program and perhaps automate that, if possible. The "external program" is what you need in order to take care of the many fiddly issues involved with dialing the number, negotiating with the receiver, and so on.

One example of an external program to send faxes is OpenOffice
http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/faxing-openofficeorg

Finally, there is fax4j in Java which you could try and use with Inline::Java, which is kind of cheating in the sense that it is just barely a Perl solution.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fax4j/

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline-Java/Java.pod

If any of this matches something that you can try out in your environment go ahead and then post back in more detail if you run into trouble implementing.